# Setting Cron path for whatever not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, cron

My other Q was closed as they said it was a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5835675/setting-path-for-whenever-in-cron-so-it-can-find-ruby).

That answer didnt work though unfortunately.

Basically I'm trying to get Whenever to run my refresh_sitemaps automatically.

The interesting thing in my cron.log file it looks like this (note the weird characters):

```
/usr/bin/ruby: No such file or directory -- °¯Ø (LoadError)
/usr/bin/ruby: No such file or directory -- Ø½ô (LoadError)
/usr/bin/ruby: No such file or directory -- à=Ù (LoadError)
```

This is whats in my **schedule.rb**:

```
env :PATH, '/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin'
set :output, "#{path}/log/cron.log"

every 1.day, :at => '3:00 pm' do
  rake "-s sitemap:refresh"
end
```

When i run `cap refresh_sitemaps` it works perfectly, it just doesnt work when it tries to run on its own as a Cron job.

i'm positive the path to ruby is correct from that PATH above. This is the result if I SSH in and run the following:

```
user@example.com [~]# /usr/local/bin/ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]
```

the weird thing is it doesnt seem to even see my "path", as its still looking in /usr/bin/ruby.

The other weird thing is there is actually something there.... as per this ssh command:

```
user@example.com [~]# /usr/bin/ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]
```

### UPDATE

When I run `crontab -l` this is what I get. Notice the extra paths I added, that was from a mediatemple help guide I found for this issue (although it didnt give any other descriptions about this):

```
# Begin Whenever generated tasks for: APPNAME
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin
GEM_HOME=/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
GEM_PATH=/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
RUBYLIB=/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1

10 17 * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/USER/u/apps/APPNAME/releases/20120731204722 && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake -s sitemap:refresh --silent >> /home/USER/u/apps/APPNAME/releases/20120731204722/log/cron.log 2>&1'

# End Whenever generated tasks for: APPNAME
```

I have tried running this by itself after i SSH in and it runs fine:

`/bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/USER/u/apps/APPNAME/releases/20120731204722 && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake -s sitemap:refresh --silent`

Comment: What does the crontab that is generated look like? The log output make me wonder if it is an encoding issue, but it is a good idea to break this down and see if the generated crontab is correct first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a stray UTF-8 character in my titles (which was then in the sitemap). How frustrating ;0