# How to put filename in cron job (rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, cron

I am using whenever gem. I am calling runner to run job. I called runner for the same job by 3 type. I am not sure which one working here.

I used command `whenever --update-crontab project_name`
 then `crontab -l`

**Schedule.rb**

```
set :output, 'log/whenever.log'
every 1.days , :at => '03:51 pm' do 

 runner "SomeJob.perform_later", filename: '/app/jobs/some_job.rb'
end

every 1.days , :at => '03:51 pm' do
  runner "SomeJob.perform_later", filename: './app/jobs/some_job.rb'
end

every 1.days , :at => '03:51 pm' do
  runner "SomeJob.perform_later"
end
```

Also these ran only once. I am having difficult time to debug here.

Can anyone tell which one is correct? Also what is the correct way to debug in this scenario?

Running `crontab -l` gives me this -

```
51,51,51 16 * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/rahul/orthoweb && bin/rails runner -e production '\''InvestigationStopJob.perform_later'\'' >> log/whenever.log 2>&1
```

To run in development environment I ran this command -

```
whenever --update-crontab --set environment='development'
```

But this gives me this message -

```
## [message] Above is your schedule file converted to cron syntax; your crontab file was not updated.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues with running the jobs in development mode.
What works is that you have to close all tabs before running your job and scheduler.

There is no need to change setup of your env in schedule file.
To run in development use this

```
whenever --update-crontab --set environment='development'
```

Without specifying filename jobs does not run properly. The following line works correctly.

`every 1.days , :at => '03:51 pm' do
  runner "SomeJob.perform_later", filename: '/app/jobs/some_job.rb'
end`

Answer (score 0):

I think, that the resulting crontab contains only one of those tasks, because they were overwritten.

To be sure, check out the resulting crontab by typing `whenever`. I think that there will be only one entrance.

Comment: I ran these tasks one by one also, but got no success. I ran  `whenever ` also it didn't work. Do I need to run some thing else to run crontab in development? @maicher

Comment: Do you see any logs in your `log/whenever.log` file? If not, maybe CRON is not running. Furthermore you have to setup your env in schedule, see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5879008/2933305

Comment: Thanks for the respone. Solved the problem. It was a silly one